# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle'

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse

Out of the blue I got the error listed below.
I am using Eclipse IDE and I have Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed (both WinPython)
I don't know when this started because I have worked for a while in 2.7. I just tried some code which I am writing in Jupyter and it is not working and I wanted to debug it easier in Eclipse. When I press the debug button I get the below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Utils\PortableApps\PortableApps\Eclipse 4.6\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.0.3.201811082356\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 20, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants import IS_JYTH_LESS25, IS_PYCHARM, get_thread_id, get_current_thread_id, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely due to that your files contain a dir named `code`! The name has conflicted with the system package. Just modify the dir name `code` to any name else. It should work well!

Comment: I've been battling PyCharm for hours, couldn't get variables to show up. Moving my python code out of the "code" directory resolved the issue. I never would have guessed this; Thanks!